# How to make overlapping shapes produce a new color?

Tags: java, colors, java-2d

I'm making a game in which there will be red and blue `Shapes` moving around on screen. I've looked high and low for how to make *any*where they overlap a different color (purple). I am only using Java2D, which to my understanding does not support Shaders. I looked into drawing the red shapes to one `BufferedImage` and the blue shapes to another, then trying to use `AlphaComposite` to combine the colors and draw it to the screen, but it never produced correct results. I'm using 127,0,0 and 0,0,127 for red and blue instead of 255 because 255,0,255 looks, in my opinion, terrible for purple. I would effectively like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTuJf.png).

Comment: `anywhere they overlap a different color (purple)` Is manually coloring the overlap an option? For instance, draw each shape their respective color, then find the intersection (if any) and color separately

Comment: @copeg Yes this worked! Thanks! I'll work on an answer now for others who find this question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to copeg's suggestion, I was able to figure it out. Here is the code segment (Context: the shapes I'm drawing are attacks):

```
    //Attacks
    BufferedImage attackImg = new BufferedImage(S_WIDTH, S_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D ag = (Graphics2D) attackImg.getGraphics();
    //Make all of attackImg a transparent image
    ag.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
    ag.fillRect(0, 0, S_WIDTH, S_HEIGHT);
    ag.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver);

    //Render red attacks to attackImg
    ag.setColor(new Color(127, 0, 0, 255));
    for(Shape s : redAttacks)
        ag.fill(s);

    //Render overlap areas using composites to attackImg
    ag.setColor(new Color(127, 0, 127, 255));
    ag.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_IN));
    g.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 127, 255));
    for(Shape s : blueAttacks)
    {
        ag.fill(s);
        g.fill(s); //Render blue attacks
    }
    //Render red and purple attacks
    g.drawImage(attackImg, 0, 0, null);
```

Comment: Also note the [Area](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html) class can be used to intersect 2 shapes (could be used to draw the intersection a different color)